# How to overcome unhashable type: 'list' error, when trying to get unique values from a pandas dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique-values

I have a Pandas dataframe with Facebook data collected with Crowdtangle, where I would like to get the unique values of some of the columns.

For most of the columns, an expression like this works just fine: df.column_name.unique(). Example:

```
In: df.account_name.unique()

Out: array(['YO TE BANCO VICTOR HUGO MORALES!!!',
       'Lula de novo, com a força do povo',
       'SOCIEDADE CIVIL, LEVANTA E RESISTE !', ..., 'Steemit',
       'BOLSONARO REELEITO EM 2022',
       'WE SUPPORT HUMAN RIGHTS OF SHIAS WORLDWIDE!'], dtype=object)
```

However, for a few of the columns, such a command does not work. Instead, I get the **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**. For example, when I type this code: df.country_mentions_domestic.unique().

I have tried to look at other examples of this error message, but without luck. Can someone see what the problem might be?

Example of the full error message:

```
In: df.country_mentions_domestic.unique()

Out: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8k/lzt5y36n293d8wkk3svczgnr0000gn/T/ipykernel_2389/3653985748.py in <module>
----> 1 df_fb.country_mentions_domestic.unique()
      2 # print()
      3 # print(df_country_mentions_en.unique())
      4 # print()
      5 # print(df_country_mentions_ru_text.unique())

/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.1.10/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in unique(self)
   2037         Categories (3, object): ['a' < 'b' < 'c']
   2038         """
-> 2039         return super().unique()
   2040 
   2041     @overload

/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.1.10/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in unique(self)
    977                     result = np.asarray(result)
    978         else:
--> 979             result = unique1d(values)
    980 
    981         return result

/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.1.10/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in unique(values)
    429 
    430     table = htable(len(values))
--> 431     uniques = table.unique(values)
    432     uniques = _reconstruct_data(uniques, original.dtype, original)
    433     return uniques

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

It means at least one (if not more) of the values in that column is a `list` not a string.

The `.unique()` function compares values in the column to each other using their hash values. Because python lists are mutable (ie they can change content), they can't have a fixed hash value associated with them.

You can figure out which ones with something like this:

```
df[[isinstance(val, list) for val in df.country_mentions_domestic.values]]
```

If you really need some of them to have collections of values, you can change your lists into tuples (or into strings separated by something like a semicolon). Tuples are not mutable, so they can be hashed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

I tried the "df[[isinstance..."-command, and the result is the length of the whole dataframe (so all values seem to be a 'list'). 

I therefore tried to change the whole column into a tuple. But the following code yields the same typeerror as above (unhashable type: 'list'):   'FIRST LINE: df.country_mentions_en = tuple(df.country_mentions_en), SECOND LINE:
df.country_mentions_en.unique()'.     Do you have an idea how to proceed instead?

Comment: Each item in the column seems to be a list, so you need to change them to tuples one at a time. Change the first line to: `df.country_mentions_en = [tuple(l) for l in df.country_mentions_en.values]`

Comment: Alternatively, if you want the unique list elements in the lists, you need to unpack them. EG, if your column has two tuples: `('A', 'B')` and `('B', 'C')`, then the output of `.unique()` will be `('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')`. But if you want `'A', 'B', 'C'` as the output, one approach is to use the `chain` function from `itertools` to unpack them, and the `set` data structure to  get the unique values: `set(chain(*df.column_name))`